# nodejs and mysql rest API

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

trying to use query param using MySQL and NodeJS but not getting any response from console and as in output getting all students details.

```
app.get('/api/students', (req, res) => {

const name = req.query.name;
console.log(name);

if(!name) {
    return res.status(400).send('Keyword parameter is required');
}

const query = 'select * from students where name like ?';
db.query(query, [`%${name}%`], (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error("Error retreiving students:", err);
        res.status(500).send('Error retreiving students');
    }else {
        res.status(200).json(result);
    }
});
```

});

I don't want all students details I need student with name containing specific character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your route is a `get` request and you are trying to extract the `name` value from the `req.query` object. For that to happen you need to pass the name in the `url` like so:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/api/students?name=sally
```

Express will take the `name=sally` part and make it accessible via the `req.query` object.

The reason your `console.log(name);` is not logging anything is because the `url` being accesses by the client browser is not appending `name=sally` when making the request. This has a knock-on effect to your `SQL` query because you think you are passing in `%sally%` to the where clause but in an actual fact you are passing in just `%%` which is a wildcard and will return  all records.